# É possível saber em que ponto o script atinge o pico de memória?

Tags: php, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória

É possível saber em que ponto o script atinge o pico de memória?

Eu tenho um script PHP que no final mostra este resultado:

> Uso: 380.515625Kb
>
> Pico: 393.5859375Kb
>
> Real: 512Kb

Exemplo:

```
<?php

...

echo PHP_EOL,
    'Uso: ', memory_get_usage() / 1024, 'Kb', PHP_EOL,
    'Pico: ',  memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024, 'Kb',  PHP_EOL,
    'Real: ',  memory_get_usage(true)  / 1024, 'Kb';
?>
```

O *Pico* é *~13kb* maior que o *Uso*. É possivel saber em que parte do código o script atingiu o pico do uso da memoria?

Answer (score 2):

Isso é possível através de um profiler.

Algumas opções são o [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), [xhprof](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xhprof.php) e o [blackfire.io](https://blackfire.io). Você precisaria instalar em seu servidor a extensão respectiva e analisar o profiler em busca da informação desejada, no seu caso onde ocorre o pico de memória.